# How do you copy things like rigidbody constraints and force fields to other objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

How do you copy things like rigidbody **constraints** and force fields to other objects?

I made a cell fracture and I would like to give each cell the same constraints and force fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is a copy physics settings in the physics tab "on the left" and you can copy constraints "type in space bar copy constraints" and if you enable "copy attribute menu" addon use Ctrl+C

Comment: @Chebhou yeah it works to search in space bar for it

Comment: does that solve the problem ?

Comment: @Chebhou it doesn't work. It changes the settings to existing rigid body constraints  but it doesn't add new ones. I need it to copy the setting but also add new ones to where there isn't rigidbody constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to add force field to all selected objects :

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
    bpy.ops.object.forcefield_toggle()
```

to run the script copy it and paste in the text editor and cick **Run Script**

- to copy constraints from one object to others :

[image]

- to copy **rigid body constraints** select the objects while the active object is the one with constraints and run this script :

  ```
   import bpy

   Type = bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.type
   obj1 = bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.object1
   obj2 = bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.object2
   use_br = bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.use_breaking
   over_itr = bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.use_override_solver_iterations
   for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects :
       bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
       bpy.ops.rigidbody.constraint_add(type = Type)
       bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.object1 = obj1 
       bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.object2 = obj2 
       bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.use_breaking = use_br 
       bpy.context.active_object.rigid_body_constraint.use_override_solver_iterations = over_itr
  ```

**Blender >2.8**
Line 9 has to be changed to:

```
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand how python works or how to add a script. And how would it work to add constraints to every object?

Comment: you can add constraints with the copy option that i gave you in the comment, this answer is to add forcefield only

Comment: i will edit to include the constraints

Comment: It's not working. I have the active object as the one with constraints but it still doesn't add constraints to the other object. It just only has the rigidbody setting in the physics tab and no rigid body constraint

Comment: ok , i'll edit to include the physics constraints

Comment: if there is a problem in the script just ask , because i struggled with the formatting of CODE in the answer