# How to create a fully linked duplicate object?

Tags: objects, rigid-body-simulation, linked-data, force-fields, instances

Hi this is my first question on this site so if I made a mistake, please advise me!

Q:
Im trying to create duplicate from a "template" cube (I created a cube and put it in the layer 2)
Now when Im making linked duplicate from this template cube I see that the rigid-body and force field that I applied on the "template" cube are missing...

I don't want to create a fully separate object for every instance of the template cube I will make...Because there will be a crap ton of them...

Comment: When creating a linked duplicate, you only link the data of the object, the geometry, texures, ... all other element will be copied but not linked (modifiers, contsraints, ...). Depending of what you want to do there is maybe another solution, but it is difficult to answer to your problem right now. In any case i would suggest you to use python if you need to generate a bunch of items with specific caracteristics.

Comment: The object I want to create are all the same and uses all the same constraints

Comment: The rigid body and force fields should copy to the objects. Are you copying using a python script maybe? This [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24730/935) may also help.